# How to serve React App on NodeJS another path

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have my regular Express NodeJS app on my domain [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). Right now I try to have react app on [www.example.com/blog](http://www.example.com/blog). I was trying this approach:

https://medium.com/@achillesmoraites/serve-a-react-app-with-express-server-c5986769bac

My directory looks like this:

```
-server
  -client
   -build
    -static
     -js
      -.js files
 -public
  .css .js etc.
 -server.js
```

With client folder (react) and server folder with regular NodeJS app, but it failed due to error:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1NhU.png

I changed homepage on package.json in my client folder on example.com/blog. I also changed Content Security Policy but also failed. In my server.js file I have:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I also added:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'static')));
```

But without success. Is there any way to serve react app on another path and having regular NodeJS app on other paths?

*Edit React on frontend and Node.js on both front and back*

Comment: You mean a monolithic application with React on the front end and Node.js on the back end, or with React on the front end and Node.js on both ends (front and back)?

Comment: The second option - React on front end and Node.js on both ends

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to determine security-policies

for example:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader(
    'Content-Security-Policy',
    "default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';"
  );
  next();
});
```

Comment: Yes I tried both: 
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
        "default-src": ["'self'"],
        "script-src": ["'self'", 
        "'unsafe-inline'", "''unsafe-eval''",
            "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/",
            "https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/"
        ],
        "img-src": ["'self'", 'www.gstatic.com'],
        "frame-src": ["'self'", "https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/", "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/"],
        "base-uri": "none"
    }
}))

And also without any security policy and still have this issue